# Triple/dual monitors will not come back after Blank screen 1080

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I have Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome desktop. 
3 Monitors connected with DP to Nvidia 1080.
Blank screen setup for 5 minutes. 8 out 2 my monitors will never turn back on after blank screen shuts them down. It make come back for a second before you can press ESC to unlock they will turn off.

What could be the issue and how can I fix it.

Comment: I am glad that someone has time to edit my message and capitalize Nvidia and Gnome, but is there anyone has any solution to my issue? I feel like going back to Windows 10...